# $l^1 \subseteq l^2 \subseteq l^\infty$ proof

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I am trying to prove $l^1 \subseteq l^2 \subseteq l^\infty$. I was able to prove $$\Vert x\Vert_\infty \le \Vert x\Vert _2 \le \Vert x\Vert_1$$
in finite-dimensional space $\mathbb R^n$. However, I have been struggling to extend the above inequalities into the infinite-dimensional space $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If $(x_n)\in \ell_1$, there is an integer $N$ such that $n\ge N\Rightarrow |x_n|<1$. Then, $\sum^{\infty}_{n=N}|x_n|^2<\sum^{\infty}_{n=N}|x_n|<\infty$, which gives the first inclusion. And the same reasoning shows that if $(x_n)\in \ell_2$ then $\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}(|x_n|)$ is bounded, from which the second inclusion follows.

Let $x=(x_n)$ and $\epsilon>0$. For the first norm inequality, find an integer $N$ such that $\|x\|_{\infty}<|x_N|-\epsilon.$ Then, $$\|x\|_{\infty}<|x_N|-\epsilon\le \sqrt{\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}|x_n|^2}-\epsilon=\|x\|_2-\epsilon$$ and the result follows.

For the second inequality, use the fact that $f(t)=\sqrt t$ is concave and $f(0)=0$, so that  that for fixed $N$, hence for all integers $n$,

$$\|\ x \|_2 =  \sqrt{ \sum_{n=1}^{N} | x_n |^{2} } \leq \sum_{n=1}^{N} \sqrt{ | x_ n |^{2} } =  \sum_{n=1}^{N} |x_n| = \|\ x \|_1$$

Comment: I think the OP wanted to prove the bounds between the norm. Not just the inclusions.

Comment: I thought he/she just wanted to use them to prove the inclusions. No harm in doing it, though. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much. For the second part of your answer, i.e. the proof for $\Vert x\Vert_\infty\le\Vert x \Vert_2 \le \Vert x\Vert _1 $, is $x=(x_n)_n \in l_1$?

Comment: @Matematleta, Shouldn't it be $+\epsilon$ instead on $-\epsilon$? The inequality $\|x\|_\infty <|x_N|-\epsilon$ doesn't make sense, it's saying the  greatest component of x is smaller than one of the components -$\epsilon$. The definition of sup yields $\forall \epsilon \exists N :\|x\|_\infty <|x_N| +\epsilon$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof of the bounds. Consider

$$
p_n := \frac{|x_n| }{\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|}
$$

which defines a discrete probability: $0\le p_n \le 1$ and $\sum_n p_n =1$. 
Clearly

$$
p_n^2 \le p_n
$$

summing both sides we get

$$\parallel x \parallel_2 \, \le \, \parallel x \parallel_1$$

For the other inequality use

$$
\sup_n |x_n|^2 \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^2
$$

but $\sup_n |x_n|^2 = \left ( \sup_n |x_n| \right )^2$. Hence we get

$$
\parallel x \parallel_\infty \, \le \, \parallel x \parallel_2
$$